# Select Multiple columns that were sum of certain rows by key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem on selecting columns that were sum of certain rows.

Lets say we have data:

```
date        key value
--------------------------
2019-04-14  A       1    
2019-04-14  B       2    
2019-04-14  C       3    
2019-04-14  D       4    
2019-04-14  E       5
```

I want to group the row into two with specific key and sum the value each of the group.

Lets say create Group `X` consists `[A, C, D]`'s sum value and group `Y` consists `[B, E]`'s sum value.

So in the end we desired to have two columns like:

```
X   Y
-----
8   7
```

My query doesn't work:

```
SELECT SUM(a.value) as X, SUM(b.value) as Y
FROM table a, table b
WHERE a.date='2019-04-14' AND b.date=a.date AND a.code IN ('A', 'C', 'D') AND b.code IN ('B', 'E)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that is a self-join in your query (i.e. joining the same table back onto itself) then what I think you want is:

```
SELECT SUM(case when A.code IN ('A', 'C', 'D') then A.value else 0 end) as X
  , SUM(case when A.code IN ('B', 'E') then A.value else 0 end) as Y
FROM table A
```

You don't need any joins / complex SQL, just a conditional sum.